# JSON Parsing in PHP Not Working

Tags: php, json, parsing

I'm attempting my first parsing of JSON with PHP and having some issues. I've searched around and even followed some solutions from SO however no luck.

So my PHP looks like:

```
$string = file_get_contents("SOME_URL_HERE");
$json_a = json_decode($string);

foreach($json_a->items as $mydata)

    {
         echo $mydata->uploader . "\n"; 
    }
```

And that JSON url shows data that looks like (I've cut this down slightly):

```
{
 'apiVersion': '2.1',
 'data': {
   'updated': '2013-03-21T16:27:35.191Z',
   'totalItems': 18620,
   'startIndex': 1,
   'itemsPerPage': 5,
   'items': [
     {
       'id': 'DiiDwOJqwQg',
       'uploaded': '2012-12-22T15:20:51.000Z',
       'updated': '2013-03-18T14:44:08.000Z',
       'uploader': 'paramountmoviesuk',
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: _Parsing_ is right with all chance, your problem is with data transversing - see Crisp answer here below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `items` are in `data`, so you probably need to do this

```
foreach($json_a->data->items as $mydata)
```

Comment: Awesome thats it! I see what how to handle/traverse now - cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try `json_decode( $string, true);` then you can easily reach with `$mydata['uploader']`

EDIT : you can loop it through with this statement if you don't want to use object mapping;

```
foreach( json_a['data']['items'] as $my_data)
{
    echo $my_data['uploader'] . "\n";
}
```

if it's not working, please make sure that it is a valid json in [this](http://jsonlint.com/) website

Comment: Tried that from what i read on php.net tutorials. Didn't work